# Replicate a bunch of syntax (multiple lines) to 20 times with various objects

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I would like to create a markdown document for a report. I have twenty objects (named as letters). The objects are various summary tables, and given letters as names. 
All objects need to go in chunks (in Rstudio markdown) to generate tables. I use knitr to create the report.

`list<- dput(unlist(letters[1:20]))`

The above command generate all the tables that need to go into chunks.
The object names are saved in list.

Now I need to create a markdown document and it need to contain chunks

```` '```{r summary_table, results='asis'}
kable(a, digits=1, align='r' )
```' ````

```` '```{r summary_table, results='asis'}
kable(b, digits=1, align='r' )
```' ````

.. goes up to..

```` '```{r summary_table, results='markdown'}
kable(t, digits=1, align='r' )
```' ````

How do I make this syntax generated in few steps? A little bit idea would help me going.

I can see the table by get("a") in console.
`lapply(list, function(x) get(x))` gets me a list including all tables.
I think I need to work along that line. But not sure how to insert each letters in 
the middle of code chunk.

Thank you in advance.

```` a<-"\n\n```{r summary_table, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(a, digits=1, align='r' )
```\n\n" ````

and

`cat(rep(a, each=20))` gets me somewhere. Any idea how I can repace that 'a' with characters from list?

Comment: Why separate chunks?

Comment: Coz I will add text between chunks. It's for a report.

Comment: In markdown, R syntax need to be in chunks. Between syntax you can write your text. So I am thinking of generating this chunks (twenty one after one) and write as a text file. It will have all the code hunks, so I don't need to create 20 different chunk in markdown manually. Then copy-paste text file content in markdown page, and there I will add my text between chunks. Right now I have 20 tables. In the future it can go to 100 objects.

Comment: Hey @Zx8754, Thnk you for your answer. Yeah along that line. I tested it and it creates only one chunk. May be I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

````
#dummy list
mylist <-
  list(a=data.frame(x=runif(10)),
       b=data.frame(x=runif(10)),
       c=data.frame(x=runif(10)))

#make temporary Rmd file
write.table(
  paste0(
    "```{r summary_table",names(mylist),", results='asis'}
kable(mylist['",names(mylist),"'], digits=1, align='r' )
```"),
  "temp.Rmd",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,quote=FALSE)
````

Output - `temp.Rmd`

````
```{r summary_tablea, results='asis'}
kable(mylist['a'], digits=1, align='r' )
```
```{r summary_tableb, results='asis'}
kable(mylist['b'], digits=1, align='r' )
```
```{r summary_tablec, results='asis'}
kable(mylist['c'], digits=1, align='r' )
```
````

Answer (score 0):

@ zx8754, It works :) Yours is easier & straightforward. I didn't think of `paste`

I was trying to go along this line..

```` a<-"\n\n```{r summary_table, results='asis'}
knitr::kable(a, digits=1, align='r' )
```\n\n" ````

and

`cat(rep(a, each=20))`

These two can go into a function and I might be able to specify how many replications of chunk I need. How do I replace object name in that syntax (where `a` is now)? It would help in some other scenarios. Thank you!